# How to get the highest probability records from the collection. (Show most time searched)

Tags: mongodb, search, mongodb-query, aggregate, probability

I am creating application where it contains many dropdowns(more than 20), user can select any dropdowns to get the results. Every user login they are selecting dropdowns and get the results.
What I am doing is, storing all the selected dropdown values of each user(basically search string), planning to show your common searches, where they can just copy that search string and get the results.

Dropdown selection is mutiple

Intention is reducing the effort of selecting dropdowns if they have most common/almost common search they have.  My dataset looks like below data stored in MongoDB.

This data is for single user, likewise it contains for all users.

```
{
  "UserID": "123",
  "SearchData": [
    {
      "searchText": "Area=[Bengaluru,Mumbai] Street_Number=[123,787] Locality=[Hebala,Electronic City] Branch=India",
      "searchDateTime": "2020-04-03"
    },
    {
      "searchText": "Area=Delhi Street_Number=[123,797,753,64] Locality=[Rajbhava,Redfort]",
      "searchDateTime": "2020-04-04"
    },
    {
      "searchText": "Region=[Asia,Europe] Branch=[India,Germany] Area=Delhi",
      "searchDateTime": "2020-04-02"
    },
    {
      "searchText": "Area=[Bengaluru,Mumbai] Team_name=[Team 1, Team 2] IsNewTeam=1 Region=[Asia,Europe] Branch=India",
      "searchDateTime": "2020-03-04"
    },
    {
      "searchText": "Region=United_States Branch=NewYork Team=[Team 1,Team 4] Locality=WTO",
      "searchDateTime": "2020-04-04"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Results like:
Your most searched/selected fields and Values are(Results for last 150 days **searchText**), Because I am planning not to keep Old data

```
1. Area=[Bengaluru,Mumbai] Branch=India Team 1 // Since this is common in many stings(Ex: Here in two strings)
2. Region=[Asia,Europe]
3. Branch=India
4. Team =Team 1
5. Area=[Bengaluru,Mumbai] 
6. IsNewTeam == //If any common match found.
7. Area =  //If any other common values found Expect the **Bengaluru,Mumbai** 
           //Ex : Dehli, Noida. This should come here
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please, can you provide expected result?

Comment: Hi @Valijon I added the results , Thanks.

Comment: How are you storing this data? Where are you storing this data?

Comment: @SunandPadmanabhan, This is the JSON structure(same as mentioned above) data storing in MongoDB